# spring jmx visual diagram or components interaction

Tags: jmx, spring-jmx

I am a new bie to the world of JMX and I was going through spring JMX and specially the spring recipes book also so that can learn more about spring jmx , while I  was also going through this url which explains a great about spring jmx http://tedone.typepad.com/blog/java/ .. but please share any url or something in which graphically the components interaction is been shown or any diagram is shown , I want an visual diagram or some thing is shown that will help to grasp more about jmx.

Comment: It's not clear how a diagram will help. An `Object` in Java is an instance of a `Class`. In the simplest terms, an `MBean` is simply a mechanism to get external access to attributes (properties) and operations (methods) on such an instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,could you please share url or amy example in post where complete spring jmx with xml one is shown clearly with a simple example as i want to grasp completely the spring jmx

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jmx+architecture+diagram

All Spring does is make it much easier to expose MBeans.